# Grouped Bar-Chart, all four in a panel

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am tryin to show all four graphs in a single panel page. Also, I want to see my graphs being very professional for beamer presentation in a single frame. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{12cm}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[font=\normalsize]
\begin{axis}
[xbar,width=22cm,height=12cm,bar width=20pt,enlargelimits=0.20,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align=horizontal, 
%xmajorgrids = true,
point meta=x * 1, % The displayed number.
xlabel={\textbf{Percentage of Cost}},
tick align=outside,
xtick={0,5,...,100}, 
ytick={1,...,5},
yticklabels={Penalty Cost, Fixed Cost, Operating and Maintenance Cost, Purchase Cost}]
\addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50]
coordinates {(0,1) (4.1,2) (16.8,3) (54.4,4)};
\addlegendentry{\text{MRI Scanning Machine}}

\addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] 
coordinates {(14.5,1) (4.6,2) (1.3,3) (4.3,4)};
\addlegendentry{\text{CT Scanning Machine}}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
\caption{Percentages of Cost Components for MRI and CT scanning machines}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{12cm}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[font=\normalsize]
\begin{axis}
[xbar,width=22cm,height=12cm,bar width=20pt,enlargelimits=0.20,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align=horizontal,
point meta=x * 1, % The displayed number.
xlabel={\textbf{Percentage of Cost}},
tick align=outside,
xtick={0,5,...,100}, 
ytick={1,...,5},
yticklabels={Penalty Cost, Fixed Cost, Operating and Maintenance Cost, Purchase Cost}]
\addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50]
coordinates {(26.9,1) (3.5,2) (9.0,3) (34.4,4)};
\addlegendentry{\text{MRI Scanning Machine}}

\addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] 
coordinates {(18.6,1) (3.3,2) (0.9,3) (3.4,4)};
\addlegendentry{\text{CT Scanning Machine}}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
\caption{Percentages of Cost Components for MRI and CT scanning machines}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{12cm}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[font=\normalsize]
\begin{axis}
[xbar,width=22cm,height=12cm,bar width=20pt,enlargelimits=0.20,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align=horizontal,
point meta=x * 1, % The displayed number.
xlabel={\textbf{Percentage of Cost}},
tick align=outside,
xtick={0,5,...,100}, 
ytick={1,...,5},
yticklabels={Penalty Cost, Fixed Cost, Operating and Maintenance Cost, Purchase Cost}]
\addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50]
coordinates {(0.0,1) (11.5,2) (22.3,3) (60.8,4)};
\addlegendentry{\text{MRI Scanning Machine}}

\addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] 
coordinates {(0.0,1) (1.2,2) (2.3,3) (1.9,4)};
\addlegendentry{\text{CT Scanning Machine}}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
\caption{Percentages of Cost Components for MRI and CT scanning machines}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{12cm}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[font=\normalsize]
\begin{axis}
[xbar,width=22cm,height=12cm,bar width=20pt,enlargelimits=0.20,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align=horizontal,
point meta=x * 1, % The displayed number.
xlabel={\textbf{Percentage of Cost}},
tick align=outside,
xtick={0,5,...,100}, 
ytick={1,...,5},
yticklabels={Penalty Cost, Fixed Cost, Operating and Maintenance Cost, Purchase Cost}]
\addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50]
coordinates {(0.0,1) (9.8,2) (31.6,3) (49.6,4)};
\addlegendentry{\text{MRI Scanning Machine}}

\addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] 
coordinates {(0.0,1) (2.6,2) (1.8,3) (4.6,4)};
\addlegendentry{\text{CT Scanning Machine}}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}
\caption{Percentages of Cost Components for MRI and CT scanning machines}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE -- please add the `\documentclass` etc. commands and `\begin{document}...\end{document}` statements in order to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I think they are a bit too big to fit in a single frame with `beamer`...

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, it is quite hard to get all those plots onto one frame. This is an approach by the `groupplots` library of »[pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)«. It certainly requires modifications depending on the used »[beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)« theme. But it might be a good starting point.

In general it needs some adjustment regarding the legend (e.g. its position and perhaps some abbreviations in the entries to make it smaller). And perhaps you want to put the complete picture into a `figure` environment. Since even `\tiny` was too big as font size, a new font size of `4pt` has been chosen which should be readable in presentation mode.

```
\documentclass[smaller,professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={group size=2 by 2},
      group/horizontal sep=2cm,
      group/vertical sep=3pc,
      group/every plot/.style={
        legend style={inner sep=0.5pt},
        xbar,
        bar width=8pt,
        enlargelimits=0.20,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=horizontal,
        point meta=x * 1,
        xlabel={\textbf{Percentage of Cost}},
        tick align=outside,
        major tick length=2pt,
        xtick={0,5,...,100},
        ytick={1,...,5},
        yticklabels={Penalty Cost, Fixed Cost, Operating and Maintenance Cost, Purchase Cost},
        y tick label style={text width=1.25cm,align=right}
      },
      width=0.45\textwidth,
      height=0.45\textheight,
      /tikz/font=\fontsize{4}{5}\selectfont  % new font size
    ]
      \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50] coordinates {(0,1) (4.1,2) (16.8,3) (54.4,4)};
        \addlegendentry{MRI Scanning Machine}

        \addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] coordinates {(14.5,1) (4.6,2) (1.3,3) (4.3,4)};
        \addlegendentry{CT Scanning Machine}

      \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50] coordinates {(26.9,1) (3.5,2) (9.0,3) (34.4,4)};
        \addlegendentry{MRI Scanning Machine}

        \addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] coordinates {(18.6,1) (3.3,2) (0.9,3) (3.4,4)};
        \addlegendentry{CT Scanning Machine}

      \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50] coordinates {(0.0,1) (11.5,2) (22.3,3) (60.8,4)};
        \addlegendentry{MRI Scanning Machine}

        \addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] coordinates {(0.0,1) (1.2,2) (2.3,3) (1.9,4)};
        \addlegendentry{CT Scanning Machine}

      \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50] coordinates {(0.0,1) (9.8,2) (31.6,3) (49.6,4)};
        \addlegendentry{MRI Scanning Machine}

        \addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] coordinates {(0.0,1) (2.6,2) (1.8,3) (4.6,4)};
        \addlegendentry{CT Scanning Machine}
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

**Addendum**

As mentioned in the comments this splits the graphs  to two frames. Furthermore there are some enhancements to make the them look a bit better.

- reduced `bar width`
- identical scaling on the x axis by fixed minimal and maximal values for more similarity
- slight shift of the bars away from the y axis by `enlarge x limits`
- legend moved to the lower right corner of the plot

Further possible enhancements are left to the interested reader.

```
\documentclass[smaller,professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={group size=1 by 2},
      group/horizontal sep=2cm,
      group/vertical sep=3pc,
      group/every plot/.style={
        legend style={inner sep=0.5pt},
        legend pos=south east,
        xbar,
        bar width=6pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.01,
        enlarge y limits=0.2,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=horizontal,
        point meta=x * 1,
        xlabel={\textbf{Percentage of Cost}},
        tick align=outside,
        major tick length=2pt,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=65,
        xtick={0,5,...,65},
        ytick={1,...,5},
        yticklabels={Penalty Cost,Fixed Cost,Operating and Maintenance Cost,Purchase Cost},
        y tick label style={text width=1.3cm,align=right}
      },
      width=0.95\textwidth,
      height=0.45\textheight,
      /tikz/font=\tiny
    ]
      \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50] coordinates {(0,1) (4.1,2) (16.8,3) (54.4,4)};
        \addlegendentry{MRI Scanning Machine}

        \addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] coordinates {(14.5,1) (4.6,2) (1.3,3) (4.3,4)};
        \addlegendentry{CT Scanning Machine}

      \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50] coordinates {(26.9,1) (3.5,2) (9.0,3) (34.4,4)};
        \addlegendentry{MRI Scanning Machine}

        \addplot[draw=blue,fill=blue!50] coordinates {(18.6,1) (3.3,2) (0.9,3) (3.4,4)};
        \addlegendentry{CT Scanning Machine}
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
      group style={group size=1 by 2},
      group/horizontal sep=2cm,
      group/vertical sep=3pc,
      group/every plot/.style={
        legend style={inner sep=0.5pt},
        legend pos=south east,
        xbar,
        bar width=6pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.01,
        enlarge y limits=0.2,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords align=horizontal,
        point meta=x * 1,
        xlabel={\textbf{Percentage of Cost}},
        tick align=outside,
        major tick length=2pt,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=65,
        xtick={0,5,...,65},
        ytick={1,...,5},
        yticklabels={Penalty Cost,Fixed Cost,Operating and Maintenance Cost,Purchase Cost},
        y tick label style={text width=1.3cm,align=right}
      },
      width=0.95\textwidth,
      height=0.45\textheight,
      /tikz/font=\tiny,
    ]
      \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50] coordinates {(0.0,1) (11.5,2) (22.3,3) (60.8,4)};
        \addlegendentry{MRI Scanning Machine}

        \addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] coordinates {(0.0,1) (1.2,2) (2.3,3) (1.9,4)};
        \addlegendentry{CT Scanning Machine}

      \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[draw=red,fill=red!50] coordinates {(0.0,1) (9.8,2) (31.6,3) (49.6,4)};
        \addlegendentry{MRI Scanning Machine}

        \addplot[draw=blue, fill=blue!50] coordinates {(0.0,1) (2.6,2) (1.8,3) (4.6,4)};
        \addlegendentry{CT Scanning Machine}
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please show 2 graphs on each frame??

Comment: @EboMensah: Didn't you ask for *four* plots on a frame? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Thanks but I think the graphs look very small. Is there anyway it could be 2 graphs on a frame? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @EboMensah: How should these two graphs be aligned, side by side or one beneath the other?

Comment: Can yo please do them one beneath please. I really appreciate all help you are providing. Thanks.

Comment: @EboMensah: See the addendum in my updated answer.